# HttpPatch not updating data in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following code in .NET Core

Mi Controller

```
[HttpPatch]
[Route("description/{id}")]
public Task<ActionResult<Video>> UpdateVideoDescription(int id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<Video> descriptionPatch)
    {
        return _repository.UpdateVideoDescription(id, descriptionPatch);
    }
```

Mi repository

```
public async Task < ActionResult < Video >> UpdateVideoDescription(int id, JsonPatchDocument < Video > descriptionPatch) {
 var video = await _context.Videos.FindAsync(id);
 descriptionPatch.ApplyTo(video);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
 return Ok(video);
}
```

But for some reason the description is not being updated in the database... I have tried with the following request

```
{
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/description",
    "value": "New Description"
}
```

and

```
{
    "description" : "New Description"
}
```

None of these works. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot update your object before save it to database.

```
...
descriptionPatch.ApplyTo(video);
_context.Update(video); // add this before you save changes
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
return Ok(video);
...
```

Comment: Does your video object change as well before you want to save chages? Check it in debugger

Comment: Nop. It does not.